# Tkinter: can't open window after destroy one (closed)

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry for the question but I'm a beginner.
The code below creates a tkinter window that checks for updates but the code below '#window 1' doesn't work with code below '#window 2' in the same code:

```
import os, sys, threading, gdown
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser as wb
from pathlib import Path
folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
folder2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])) + "/images/"
folder_logs = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])) + "/log_files/"
global downl
downl = 0

# window 1

updates = tk.Tk()
updates.title("Suche nach Updates")

width = 300
height = 100
screen_width = updates.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = updates.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)

updates.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
updates.configure(bg="#fff")
updates.resizable(width=False, height=False)
image_icon = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'download_icon.png')
updates.wm_iconphoto(False, image_icon)

def leave1():
     updates.destroy()
     updates.quit()
     sys.exit()

def search():
     def download():
          global downl
          downl = 0
          # download file
          if os.path.isdir(folder + "/download") == False:
               os.makedirs(folder + "/download")
          else:
               if os.path.exists(folder + "/download/UT-version.txt") == True:
                    os.remove(folder + "/download/UT-version.txt")
          gdown.download(url='dowload link', output=folder + "/download/UT-version.txt", quiet=False)
          downl = 1
     def run():
          global downl
          while downl == 0:
               string = "Updates gesucht "
               l1.config(text=string)
               for n in range(3):
                    string = string + "."
                    l1.config(text=string)
                    sleep(0.5)
               string = "Updates gesucht ..."
               for m in range(3):
                    string = string[:-1]
                    l1.config(text=string)
                    sleep(0.5)
          updates.destroy()
          updates.quit()
     Thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run)
     Thread1.daemon = True
     Thread1.start()
     Thread2 = threading.Thread(target=download)
     Thread2.daemon = True
     Thread2.start()

updates.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", leave1)
img1 = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'download_img.png')
pic = Label(updates, image=img1, border=0, bg='white').place(x=0, y=7)
Label(updates, border=0, text="Es wird nach", bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 15)).place(x=90,y=20)
l1 = Label(updates, border=0, text="Updates gesucht ", bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 15))
l1.place(x=90,y=45)
updates.after(0, search)
updates.mainloop()

# read files
downloaded_txt = ""
with open(folder + "/download/UT-version.txt", 'r') as file:
     for line in file:
          if "Version:" in line.rstrip():
               downloaded_txt = line.rstrip().replace("Version:", "")
file.close()

existing_txt = "Version:1.0.0-NoUpdate"
if os.path.exists(folder + "/UT-version.txt") == True:
     with open(folder + "/UT-version.txt", 'r') as file:
          for line in file:
               if "Version:" in line.rstrip():
                    existing_txt = line.rstrip().replace("Version:", "")
     file.close()
else:
     with open(folder + "/UT-version.txt", 'w+') as file:
          file.write("Version:1.0.0-NoUpdate")
     file.close()

# window 2

if str(existing_txt) != str(downloaded_txt):
     window = tk.Tk()
     window.title('Ein Update ist verfügbar')
     width = 525
     height = 175
     screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
     screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
     x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
     y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)

     window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
     window.configure(bg="#fff")
     window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
     image_icon = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'download_icon.png')
     window.wm_iconphoto(False, image_icon)

     def leave2():
          window.destroy()
          window.quit()
          sys.exit()

     def later():
          window.withdraw()
          achtung = Toplevel()
          achtung.title("Achtung !")

          width = 375
          height = 100
          screen_width = achtung.winfo_screenwidth()
          screen_height = achtung.winfo_screenheight()
          x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
          y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)

          achtung.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
          achtung.configure(bg="#fff")
          achtung.resizable(width=False, height=False)
          image_icon = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'icon_warning.png')
          achtung.wm_iconphoto(0, image_icon)

          def back():
               achtung.destroy()
               sleep(0.1)
               window.deiconify()
          def leave():
               achtung.destroy()
               sys.exit()
          def destroy():
               achtung.destroy()
               window.destroy()

          achtung.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", leave2)
          img1 = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'img_warning.png')
          Label(achtung, image=img1, border=0, bg='white').place(x=15, y=18)
          Label(achtung, border=0, text="Beachte, dass es zu Problemen führen kann,", bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 10)).place(x=90,y=20)
          Label(achtung, border=0, text="die Version nicht zu aktualisieren.", bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 10)).place(x=90,y=39)
          Button(achtung, text='Zurück', width=16, height=0, bg='#57a1f8', pady=0, fg='white', border=0, font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light', 10), command=back).place(x=92, y=65)
          Button(achtung, text='Ich verstehe', width=16, height=0, bg='#57a1f8', pady=0, fg='white', border=0, font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light', 10), command=destroy).place(x=233, y=65)
          achtung.mainloop()

     def now():
          wb.open('open browser')
          sys.exit()

     version, release, newfile_size = "", "", ""
     oldfile_size = float(sum(file.stat().st_size for file in Path(folder).glob('**/*') if file.is_file()) / 1000000)
     with open(folder + "/download/UT-version.txt", 'r') as file:
          for line in file:
               if "Version:" in line.rstrip():
                    version = line.rstrip().replace("Version:", "")
               elif "Release:" in line.rstrip():
                    release = line.rstrip().replace("Release:", "")
               elif "File-Size:" in line.rstrip():
                    newfile_size = float(line.rstrip().replace("File-Size:", "").replace("MB", ""))
     file.close()

     difference = str(round(float(newfile_size) - float(oldfile_size), 2)).replace(".", ",")
     window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", leave2)
     img1 = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'download_img_large.png')
     pic = Label(window,image=img1, border=0, bg='white').place(x=25, y=25)
     Label(window, text="Es ist ein Update verfügbar !", border=0, bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 18)).place(x=145, y=15)
     Label(window, text="- Version: " + str(version), border=0, bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 13)).place(x=145, y=50)
     Label(window, text="- Größe: " + str(difference) + " MB", border=0, bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 13)).place(x=145, y=70)
     Label(window, text="- Release: " + str(release), border=0, bg='white',font =("Microsoft YaHei UI Light", 13)).place(x=145, y=90)
     Button(window, text="Später aktualisieren", width=19, height=1, bg='#57a1f8', pady=0, fg='white', border=0, font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light', 12), command=later).place(x=143, y=125)
     Button(window, text="Aktualisieren", width=19, height=1, bg='#57a1f8', pady=0, fg='white', border=0, font=('Microsoft YaHei UI Light', 12), command=now).place(x=330, y=125)
     window.mainloop()
else:
     print("Kein Update verfügbar !")#
```

The code only works with "# window 1" or "# window 2" but not in the same script.
I try to open a window after another one was destroyed but I get this error message:

```
image_icon = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'download_icon.png')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4130, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4075, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "image" command: application has been destroyed
```

But when i delete image_icon then comes this error message:

```
img1 = PhotoImage(file=folder2 + 'download_img_large.png')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4130, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4075, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "image" command: application has been destroyed
```

I now delete img1 and pic1 then the window does not open.

PLS HELP WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

I've tried everything but whenever it seems to work it gives me an error message or the second window hasn't opened

Comment: I think you can fix this by adding a `master=window` parameter to all of the `PhotoImage()` calls you make for window #2.  By default, they are creating an image in the first-created root window - which has been destroyed by that point in the code.

Comment: Thank you but the window doesn't stay open

Answer (score 1):

Add a `master=window` parameter to all instances of `PhotoImage()` and have `window.mainloop()` twice because it skips the first `window.mainloop()`